# Angular 5, using rxjs timer, when the event will be emitted during the execution of the code?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, timer, rxjs

Maybe my question is silly, but I did not find any answer about it.

I have a timer of 3 seconds-

```
        this.timer = timer(3000, 3000);
        this.timerObservable = this.timer.subscribe(x => {
//do someting
        });
```

If I am in progress of executing a very long function (for example- after 2 seconds from the previos timer I have pressed on a button the execute a lot of logic or something like it), what will happen after a minute (3 seconds from the previos timer)? 
Does the long function will pause, the function inside the timer will be executed and then the long function will get control again, or maybe the long function will be fully executed and then the timer (although it will be after more than 3 seconds)?

Comment: It depends somewhat on what that long function is doing, but most likely it will wait until after the long function is complete. I found this very helpful in understanding how the JavaScript event loop works: http://latentflip.com/loupe

Comment: If the long running function is blocking then `timer` will emit with longer delays. By blocking I mean it runs eg. some synchronous computation that can't be split into multiple smaller chunks.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple smaller chunks"? I guess that a lot of long functions can be spitted to chunks?

Answer (score 0):

I found I simple way to check it:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.timer = timer(1000, 1000);
    this.timerSubscription = this.timer.subscribe(x => {
        console.log("inside timer");       
        }
    });
    while (true){
        console.log("in while");
    }
}
```

The 'inside timer' does not get called..